# Let X = the time between two successive arrivals at the drive-up window of a local bank...

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

Let $X$ = the time between two successive arrivals at the drive-up window of a local bank. $X$ has an exponential distribution with $\lambda = 2$. That is the probability density of $X$ is $f(X | \lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, X > 0 $ with $\lambda = 2$. Compute the following:

a) The expected time between two successive arrivals.

b) The standard deviation of the time between successive arrivals.

c) $P(X\le4)$

d) $(P(2\le X<5)$

**I just need someone to check my work to make sure I'm doing these right.**

I think I've got the first part.. would it be

a) $\mu = 1/2 => 30$ minutes or half an hour?

And for b) I got:

b) $\sigma^2 = 1/\lambda^2 = (1/2)^2 = (1/4)^2 = 1/16$
so $\sigma^2 = \sqrt{1/16} => \sigma = .25$ ?

c) $P(X \le 4) = 1 - e^{-2*4} \approx 0.9996$

d) $\int^5_2 2e^{-2x} dx \approx 0.018270$

Comment: For d, can a probability be greater than 1?  For c what happened to the $\lambda$ multiplier?

Comment: In addition to what was said above, I don't understand what you're doing for (b). You might want to check your arithmetic because it's wrong.

Comment: $d$ should instead be $\int^5_2 e^{-2x} dx \approx 0.0091351$ is that correct?

Comment: also for $c$ should I have $2 - e^{-2*4} \approx 1.9996$ instead ?

Comment: For c, a probability cannot be greater than 1.  **Think**

Comment: The formula states: $P(X \le 4) = F(x,\lambda) = 1-e^{-\lambda * x}$ => $F(4,2) = 1-e^{-8} = 0.9996$

Comment: It says I can either use the formula above I just posted or I can take the integral of $\int ^4 _0 2e^{-8}$ but they aren't equivalent answers so Idk why the book says to do this! Becuase $\int ^4 _0 2e^{-8} \approx 0.0026837$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) and (b) are OK.

(c) 0.9996645, so a slight rounding error at worst.

(d) In (c) you are using the PDF $F(x) = 1 - e^{-2x},$ for $x > 0$ to
find the answer. Here you need $F(5) - F(2),$ which requires no additional
integration. Just watch the signs and you'll get something close to .02.

It should be easy to make a graph of the exponential density function,
which starts at $f(0) = 2$ and descends rapidly to $f(4) \approx 0,$
then shade in appropriate areas matching the probabilities you seek.